# Dye sublimation printing on 3D printed object

Tags: color

Has anyone been able to dye sublimate 3D printed objects? Which materials work and what products are necessary?

I've been trying to find out and apparently it is supposed to be possible. But I'm not finding more detail than that. (Actually, a lot of sites say it isn't possible)

Comment: Sublimation is the transition of a solid to a gas without a liquid phase. For example, Dry Ice turns into CO2-gas via sublimation. Is that what you want to ask about?

Comment: @Trish dye sublimation is a method for sublimating dye into the surface of an object. My question asks if anyone has experience doing this on 3d printed objects sucessfully, which I assume you don't or you wouldn't be telling me about dry ice.

Comment: it is possible to powdercoat a dmls part (closest i can think of)... extruded plastic prototypes and vapor deposition though I'm not sure when that would even be worth doing versus a dip or spray.

Comment: @Abel dye sublimation allows you to infuse full colour at photographic level quality into the surface of objects so the picture cannot be damaged by scraping it off like a sticker or washing it or something. Very different from dipping or spraying because they sit above the surface and are vulnerable. It's a fairly common method of putting logos and pictures on items that expect high handling, aluminium, ceramics, plastic etc,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ABS can be dye sublimated quite easily using a press, timing is the main issue.

PLA can also be dye sublimated if you're careful but will lose a lot of volume due to the heat and pressure. Not too bad if you print solid, but with infill expect the infill to collapse, or melt (unsure which).

PETG is excellent for Dye sublimation. Like ABS it's all in the timing but the result is superior.